# How can you get a second copy of a running log file without deleting it?

Tags: unix, redirect, logging

I am trying to trouble shoot an issue on an application running on flavor of UNIX.
The default logging level puts out a reasonable amount of messages and does not affect performance.
But where there is an issue I need to change the logging level to verbose.  Thousands of line in a second.  Which effects performance.
Doing a delete of the trace log file would crash the application.
Being able to change back the logging level as quick as possible helps avoid a production performance hit.
The code is running in production so a performance hit is not good.
How can one create a second instance of the log for just the second or two that the problem is reproduced?
This would save having to copy the whole large file and then doing an edit to remove log entries not of concern for the problem at hand?

I have answered my own question because I have found this tip to be very useful at times and hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

The steps below show how to quickly get a small section of the log to a separate file.

1) Navigate to the directory with the log file that you want to clear.

```
cd /logs
```

2) At the command prompt enter the following line. e.g. (include the ">")

```
> trace.log
```

This will clear the file trace.log without a file pointer changing.

3) Now quickly reproduce the error.

4) Quickly go back to the command line and copy the trace.log file to a new file.

```
cp trace.log snippet_of_trace.log
```

5) Now you have a much small log to analyze.